# Perform operations to multiple csv files

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a folder with multiple CSV files and I would like to perform some operations on them:

I need to read them, then delete the first row of every file, create a new column called 'Date' from the filename. (Filenames are something like campaign_by_date_2019_12_10_to_2019_12_10) And then merge all files.

I have managed to join all the files but I don't know when should I perform these operations.

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
#combine all files in the list
combined_csv = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f) for f in filenames ])
```

Greetings and thanks in advance,

Andrés

Comment: Once you concatenate the dataframes in this way the information on the corresponding filename is lost

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
extension = 'csv'
all_filenames = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
all_dfs=[]
for f in all_filenames:
    #Load and remove 1st row
    temp_df = pd.read_csv(f)[1:]

    # Use filename to add data information
    temp_df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(f[-14:-4], format='%Y_%m_%d')
    all_dfs.append(temp_df)

combined_csv = pd.concat(all_dfs)
```

Remark that when slicing `f[-14:-4]` I am assuming all filenames ends with `YYYY_MM_DD.csv`

Comment: Thank you so much, just one thing, I guess it should be [-14:-4] because there are 4 characters before the date, (.csv). Otherwise, I am getting an error.

And when you append all the temp_dfs, it becames a list so you cannot concatenate it.

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly now. Just remind to update [-14:-3] to [-14:-4].

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

It will be easier to create your date column if you read the csvs in a normal for loop rather than using list comprehension they way you have here.

If you're not sure about how to use datetime to do what you want, lmk and i'll add specifics for that.

```py
combined_df = pd.DataFrame()
for filename in filenames:
    # read csv
    df = pd.read_csv(filename)
    # delete first row
    df = df.iloc[1:]
    # create date column
    df['Date'] = datetime.datetime(filename, "your_date_format")
    # combine with others
    combined_df = combined_df.append(df, sort=False)
```